# How to turn off getter/setter only for one instance non-final field? [Project Lombok]

Tags: java, setter, getter, lombok

```
public @Data class Person { ... }
```

As I know, when I mark a class with the `@Data` annotation, Lombok will provide getters for all fields, setters for all non-final fields. I want to turn off getter and setter **only** for one instance non-final field, how can I reach that?

What did I expect? To find an annotation like

```
@Setter(provide=false)
@Getter(provide=false)
private Map<...> dialogs;
```

or

```
@Data(excludeFields={"dialogs"})
```

I googled a lot and looked for on the official site, but I've found nothing.
Your help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to avoid generating Getter/Setter for a specific field, you can use **`AccessLevel.NONE`**, as described in [webpage for Getter/Setter](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html)

```
@Data
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE) @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Map<String, String> dialog;
}
```

**EDIT:** This answer originally proposed to use `AccessLevel.PRIVATE`. The correct approach is to use `AccessLevel.NONE` as @Roel_Spilker mentioned in the other answer. But this answer was accepted by the questioner. In order to avoid future confusion, I edited this to use correct approach.

Comment: I also found this way a few seconds ago, but they will be generated all the same :(

Comment: the other way is marking all fields with these annotations except those which needn't methods, but it will lead to writing a lot of duplicate code. Thank you :)

Comment: Editing answer in a such way, that "idiomatic" solution comes first would be convenient.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE) @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)` on the field as described on [the website](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html).

Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer.